# Python Script call Process.Start: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process?

Tags: c#, python, wpf

Trying to run a Python script which takes two parameters from a WPF application. I can run from cmd no problem:

[image]

This is my Python install:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe
```

I then try to invoke the script from WPF:

```
  private void CreateReportCommandAction()
    {
        try
        {
            string cmd = @"C:\temp\WebBuilder\webplus_builder.py";
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe";
            start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", cmd, "WAF", _CountryCode);
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            Process process = Process.Start(start);
        }
```

I am getting an exception in the Process object Main Module:

```
A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.
```

Stack Trace:

```
     at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(Int32 processId)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
```

Application is set to build to 'any CPU'. When I remove 'Prefer 32 bit' the exception changes to this which as I understand from reading around is linked to the same 32-64 bit interoperability issue:

```
Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed
```

Is there a known fix or workaround for this?

Comment: Are you using the 32 or 64 bit version of Python ?

Comment: Does it work if you set UseShellExecute=True ? You will have to temporarily comment out the redirection of the standard output to do this

Comment: 'Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.' unfortuantely

Comment: Is that error thrown in the catch block ?